# When running a script, two objects that are very far apart recognise as colliding

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection, collision

I've been having trouble with this code in Pygame recently, and I am not able to find my error. The script is at the moment just a controllable sprite, (which I understand is not showing as things are drawn over it) but when I run my code it thinks the small white square, (player) is colliding with the larger, (blocks.trees). The code is as such:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*

#initialise pygame
pygame.init()

WHITE = (255,255,255)

#counts which sprite you should be on when running


#create screen
screen_width = 160
screen_height = 144
screen_multiplier = 4
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(((screen_width*screen_multiplier), (screen_height*screen_multiplier)))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pokemon Blood Red')

#Sprite stuff
sprite = pygame.image.load('player_east_still.png')
#Reform the sprite
sprite = pygame.transform.scale(sprite, (10*screen_multiplier,   14*screen_multiplier))
sprite.set_colorkey(WHITE)

#############################################################################
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.player_sprite = pygame.Surface((10*screen_multiplier, 14*screen_multiplier))
        self.player_sprite.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.player_sprite.get_rect()


class Blocks(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Blocks, self).__init__()
        self.trees = pygame.Surface((20*screen_multiplier, 40*screen_multiplier))
        self.trees.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.trees.get_rect()

player = Player()
blocks = Blocks()












#############################################################################
#Random variables for later use

amount_caught = 0
place = 1
catch1 = {'pokemon':'none',
          'hp':0,
          'attack':0,
          'defence':0,
          'sp_attack':0,
          'sp_defence':0,}
background = 1
def area_load():
    global background
    if background == 1:
        background = pygame.image.load('neuory_town.png').convert()
        background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (160*screen_multiplier, 144*screen_multiplier))
area_load()
(x) = 160*0.45
(y) = 144*0.45
def caught():
    if amount_caught == 0:
        pass


#Mainloop
crashed = False
while not crashed:
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    #Different buttons
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = 5*screen_multiplier

              sprite = pygame.image.load('player_west_still.png')
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = -5*screen_multiplier

            sprite = pygame.image.load('player_east_still.png')
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            y_change = -5*screen_multiplier

            sprite = pygame.image.load('player_north_still.png')
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            y_change = 5*screen_multiplier

            sprite = pygame.image.load('player_south_still.png')

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_change = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            y_change = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            y_change = 0    
x += x_change
y += y_change

blockades = pygame.sprite.Group()
blockades.add(blocks)
#Check for collisions
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, blockades, True)
if hits:
    print ('Collision!')

#Draw everything
sprite = pygame.transform.scale(sprite, (10*screen_multiplier, 14*screen_multiplier))
sprite.set_colorkey(WHITE)
screen.blit(background,(0,0))
screen.blit(sprite,(x,y))
screen.blit(player.player_sprite, (x, y))
screen.blit(blocks.trees, (200, 200))
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
In this case, I'm looking for *minimal* code, as well as your debugging attempts -- how do you know they're colliding, and what are the values of critical variables at and leading up to that point?

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.sprite.spritecollide` checks if the `rect`s of the sprites overlap. You never move the rects to a new position after the instantiation, so both the `player` and the `blocks` are still positioned at (0, 0) (try to `print(blocks.rect, player.rect)`). To move them you can for example change the x and y coords, the topleft, center or the [other attributes](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) of the rect:

```
blocks.rect.center = (400, 500)
player.rect.topleft = (20, 40)
player.rect.x += 50
player.rect.y += 100
```

---

In your original example you're not moving the sprites, but only change the variables x and y which you use as the blit position for the image.

```
# This doesn't change the position of the rect, so there won't be collisions.
x += x_change
y += y_change
```

You should instead move the rect and then use the rect as the blit position:

```
player.rect.x += x_change
player.rect.y += y_change
screen.blit(player.player_sprite, player.rect)  # Blits the image at rect's topleft coords.
```

---

Also, the image attribute of a `pygame.sprite.Sprite` should be called `image` not `player_sprite`. Then you can put all your sprites into one `pygame.sprite.Group` and to update and draw all sprites you only need two lines of code:

```
# Before the while loop define the sprite group.
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
# Add all sprites.
all_sprites.add(player)  # And other sprites.

# In the while loop update the sprites.
all_sprites.update()
# And in the draw phase.
all_sprites.draw(screen)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I get home!

Comment: When I tried this, it still doesn't pick up collisions: I tried  I did blit them to different co-ords at the end, however.

Comment: The squares do not touch after blitted, but still don't pick up collisions!

Comment: I can only guess if you don't post your updated code. I've added more infos about moving rects.